# How do you take the divergence of a tensor?

Tags: vectors, inner-products, tensors, divergence-operator

Let's say a rank 2 tensor $\textbf{T}$ with components $T_{ij}$.

I want to take the divergence of this tensor $\nabla \cdot \textbf{T}$. How would one go about doing this?

Let's say we take the inner product of this tensor with a vector $\textbf{v}$ with components $v_{i}$, in other words $\textbf{v} \cdot\textbf{T}$. This would have components $v_i T_{ij}$ (I think).

How would one take the divergence of this? ie $\nabla \cdot (\textbf{v} \cdot \textbf{T})$?

Thank you

Comment: However you call what you calculate here: $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{T}$ is the vector $\partial_iT_{ij}$ and $\nabla\cdot(\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{T})$ is the scalar $\partial_j(v_iT_{ij})\,.$

Comment: $(\nabla\cdot T)_i=\nabla^jT_{ij}$. It's unambiguous only if $\mathbf T$ is symmetric.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, it's surprisingly hard to find a reference on divergence of general tensors. Let's say $T$ is symmetric $(0,2)$ tensor, otherwise you keep track of which slot to keep and which to kill. In local coordinates, divergence is given by $$\text{div}(T)=g^{ij}(\nabla_{\partial_i} T)(\partial_j,-).$$
For an orthonormal frame $E_i$, divergence is given by
$$\text{div}(T)=\sum_{i=1}^n (\nabla_{E_i}T)(E_i,-),$$
where $\dim M=n$. In the orthonormal frame, you'll notice that the notation $\nabla \cdot T$ for divergence is reasonable. Another notation that geometers may see is ${T_{ij}}^{;i}$.This is nice since it tells you what component to kill. In this notation, personally seen $\text{div}\text{div}T={T_{ij}}^{;ij}$. Physicists sometimes write divergence as $\text{div}(T)=\nabla^i T_{ij}$, for example [in this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/695171/how-to-compute-divergence-of-a-metric-tensor/695177#695177?newreg=7944d14178954f90a4d1da619688fb06). Beware though that they write $T_{ij}$ for (0,2) tensor, not for its components.

For your second question, I'm not sure what you mean by inner product of the $(1,0)$ tensor $v$ with the $(0,2)$ one $T$. If the dot product here means the natural pairing, i.e. evaluation, the result the $(0,1)$ tensor
$$T(v,-),$$
and it's divergence is just $\sum_i(\nabla_{E_i}T(v,-))(E_i)$ in an orthonormal frame.